# SQL max by 2 column, or first and last aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get max by colum1 1 then by colum 2 in sql? and is there aggregate function like first or last?

I tried 2 ways:

1-it's get me max date but the max price is not associated with max date:

```
SELECT doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId,MAX(price_list_t._Date), MAX (price_list_t.Price)
FROM [AcKits] kits_t
INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
 AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
 GROUP BY kits_t.DocId,kits_t.GoodId,doc_kits_t.DateOper
```

2- I have not found aggregate function to get first:

```
SELECT doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId, /*top or first*/(price_list_t._Date),/*top or first*/ (price_list_t.Price)
FROM [AcKits] kits_t
INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
 AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
 GROUP BY kits_t.DocId,kits_t.GoodId,doc_kits_t.DateOper
 ORDER BY price_list_t._Date, price_list_t.Price
```

The full explanation:

I have 3 table:

```
Table 1:
    PriceList (Id, AcProviderId, AcGoodsId, Price, _Date)
Table 2:
    DocAcKits (Id, Number, DateOper)
Table 3:
    AcKits (Id, DocId, GoodId, Count)
```

at the result i should get table:
AS

```
(DateOpr , DocId, Number, TotalPrice )
```

the TotalPrice is the sum of prices of goods that have same DocId
where link GoodId in AcKits with GoodId in PriceList It must fulfill the conditions `(DocAcKits.DateOper <= PriceList._Date` and date is max and if there more then one max date we will get max price)

Thanks for help, the final solution is:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY kits_t.GoodId,doc_kits_t.DateOper ORDER BY price_list_t._Date DESC, price_list_t.Price DESC) rn,
  doc_kits_t.DateOper as DateOper, kits_t.DocId as DocId,
   ISNULL (price_list_t.Price,0) as Price,
  kits_t.Count as Count,
  doc_kits_t.Number as Number
  FROM [AcKits] kits_t
  INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
  ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
  ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
   AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
   WHERE doc_kits_t.DateOper BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  )
  INSERT @ret
  SELECT DateOper, Number, SUM(Price * Count)as TotalPrice  FROM CTE t1
  WHERE rn = 1
  GROUP BY DocId,DateOper,Number
```

Comment: you can use a subquery to get max(price) and then just select * from mytable where price = subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` to achieve this

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY kits_t.DocId,kits_t.GoodId,doc_kits_t.DateOper ORDER BY price_list_t._Date DESC) rn,
doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId
FROM [AcKits] kits_t
INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
 AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

***Note:***

If you need `MAX` record for `price_list_t._Date` use `ORDER BY price_list_t._Date DESC`

If you need `MIN` record for `price_list_t._Date` use `ORDER BY price_list_t._Date ASC`

Comment: As a result I want to get table with max date and max price for this max date columns, but in your quary I get only rn, DateOper, DocId, GoodId

Comment: you can add appropriate columns in the select after `row_number()over(...) rn` like if you want all columns from `price_list_t` use `price_list_t.*`

Comment: Thanks for help, I add order by price desc and its work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the records for max(price) do:

```
 SELECT doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId,price_list_t._Date, price_list_t.Price
    FROM [AcKits] kits_t
    INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
    ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
    ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
    AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
    WHERE price_list_t.price = (
                                SELECT Max(price) 
                                FROM price_list_t)
    GROUP BY kits_t.DocId,kits_t.GoodId,doc_kits_t.DateOper
```

OR if you want to get by max date:

```
SELECT doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId,price_list_t._Date, price_list_t.Price
        FROM [AcKits] kits_t
        INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
        ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
        ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
        AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
        WHERE price_list_t.date= (
                                    SELECT Max(date) 
                                    FROM price_list_t)
        GROUP BY kits_t.DocId,kits_t.GoodId,doc_kits_t.DateOper
```

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding something when looking at the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Often, you would do this with `row_number()`.  I find your explanation and query a bit hard to follow, but I think you want this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY kits_t.DocId, kits_t.GoodId, doc_kits_t.DateOper
                                ORDER BY price_list_t._Date) as seqnum
      FROM [AcKits] kits_t INNER JOIN
           [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
           ON kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           [PriceList] price_list_t
           ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper AND
              kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To translate a MAX or MIN to ROW_NUMBER you simply need to move the columns from GROUP BY to PARTITION BY and ORDER BY in such a way that the row you want is the first row:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY doc_kits_t.DateOper, kits_t.DocId,kits_t.GoodId 
            ORDER BY price_list_t._Date DESC, price_list_t.Price DESC) AS rn
   FROM [AcKits] kits_t
   INNER JOIN [DocAcKits] doc_kits_t
     ON  kits_t.DocId = doc_kits_t.Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [PriceList] price_list_t
     ON price_list_t._Date <= doc_kits_t.DateOper
    AND kits_t.GoodId = price_list_t.AcGoodsId
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1:
```